# \@ifnextchar inside pmatrix?

Tags: math-mode, macros, amsmath, latex-base

I created a function which handles a superscript followed after the function. I do that by using `\@ifnextchar^`. Everything works well, except in any `pmatrix` environment. Why?

As a quick-and-dirty example I created the (useless) function `\fv` to debug it a little:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fv}[1]{
    \@ifnextchar^{A}{B}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \fv{x}, \fv{x}^y
        \end{pmatrix} = \fv{x} = \fv{x}^y
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I had expected a result in the form (B,A<sup>y</sup>)=B=A<sup>y</sup>. But what I get is (B,B<sup>y</sup>)=B=A<sup>y</sup>.

Is there a way to detect the superscript in `pmatrix` environments as well?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Related: [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is in your macro: `\@ifnextchar` is picking up the space character.

Try

```
\newcommand{\fv}[1]{%
    \@ifnextchar^{A}{B}%
}
```

The `%` I inserted masks the space, so `\@ifnextchar` has a chance to "see" the next character.

(explanation by Heiko Oberdiek:)
LaTeX's original `\@ifnextchar` gobbles spaces, thus the extra space would not hurt. But `amsmath` redefines `\@ifnextchar` inside the matrix environment. The redefined version (`\new@ifnextchar`, defined in `amsgen.sty`) does not ignore the space.

Hence, your second example, using the original `\@ifnextchar`, even works with the space in place.

[image: output]

Comment: On special request of David Carlisle, I also masked the other useless space, which will not make a difference in output, but save one full byte of main memory ;-) It's good practise anyway to get used to masking line ends, as it'll make a lot of difference outside of math mode ;-)

Comment: @StephanLehmke LaTeX's `\@ifnextchar` gobbles spaces, thus the extra space would not hurt. But `amsmath` redefines `\@ifnextchar` inside the matrix environment. The redefined version (`\new@ifnextchar`, defined in `amsgen.sty`) does not ignore the space.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thank you for the explanation! I hope you don't mind that I included it in the answer.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Thanks, that was the idea. :-)